# Why does cookie-signature in nodejs/express compare signatures using sha1-hashing?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, digital-signature, signing

I was just looking into the implementation of the cryptograhic signing extension for express which allows creation of signed cookies.

The mac in the signing function is calculated as described here:

1. create an instance of SHA256
2. hash the data value
3. create a base64 encoded digest
4. remove trailing equal characters ('=')

The result is a concatenation of the original value and the calculated mac.

On verification of the signature the value is signed again. But then not the signatures are tested on equality, but the overall strings consisting of the original value and the appended mac are compared:

```
return sha1(mac) == sha1(val) ? str : false;
```

Here "mac" contains the original value concatenated with a freshly calculated mac, "val" contains the input string as passed to the verification method (consisting of the original value concatenated with a former mac) and "str" is the signed value itself.

See: https://github.com/tj/node-cookie-signature/blob/master/index.js

I would have expected that only the macs would be compared. But this is not the case. Why have the authors chosen this way of implementing the verification? What is the reason for this? And especially: Why don't they compare char by char but a hash of sha1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation's `sign` function returns the *value* concatenated with `'.'` and [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) of the value converted to Base64 without the trailing '=' (if any).

The implementation's `unsign` function does the same with the *value* part of the given input (up to the `'.'`) and checks if the *whole* input equals the output of the `sign` function.

And as to comparing using hash values I the authors were trying to fend off [timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack), whereby an attacker would observe the time it took to check for equality character by character and determine by minute changes between two tries at what character the check failed, and thereafter try to guess on character by character basis the MAC value for the arbitary *value* part. By comparing using `sha1` digest code takes constant time depending only on the given *whole* input length.

More interesting side note is the removal of padding '=' from Base64 encoded MACs, I have no idea why would they do that as there is [URL safe variant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548#section-4) of Base64.

Comment: That explains it. This is an important detail I did not think of. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: That is the reason they chose to compare hashes, but why didn't they instead choose to do a constant-time comparison of signatures, which would be much faster than generating two SHA1 hashes and also make birthday attacks much harder because SHA1 hashes are 160 bits, while SHA256 signatures are 256 bits (both are cryptographically random)?